# Add VAT (Not TAX) to WooCommerce items, cart, checkout, Invoices/printouts/PDF's

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, woocommerce, product

I have tried various plugins such as 'WooCommerce EU VAT Compliance', WooCommerce EU VAT Appliance', 'WooCoomerce Taxomony' and many other additional plugins not linked to WooCommerce. I have also searched StackOverFlow and found similar, but not quite what I need. For starters I am working with VAT, not TAX.

1. My business is based in Thailand (e-commerce) selling physical items and I am required to Show/Produce '**MY**' VAT
   Number. This could possibly be entered via the **WooCommerce Tax
   Settings** maybe as a extra field? I would like this to be placed on
   my customers Invoices for them to see. (Other plugin examples I have
   seen allow the customer to put '**THEIR**' VAT Number in at the
   Checkout for VAT reductions which is **NOT** what I need)
2. I also want my products to have **VAT included in the price**, and
   when they head over to both the Cart & the Checkout the Sub
   Total/Totals are given as well as a **VAT calculation below the Total amount**. something like:

> Total 20,007 Baht
>
> (+ 7 Baht Vat Included)

Comment: First of all VAT is TAX, VAT is Value Added TAX so stop talking nonsense, You just need YOUR companies VAT number to be added on Invoices.And the second question is actually basic woo-commerce functionality.

Comment: Hi dExIT,

Yes I know Value Added Tax is a tax. However, I require it to be displayed as Vat as I stated I am living in Thailand, where it is not called Tax but instead Vat. This may seem simple to most people, but a LARGE amount of Thai customers are confused by this simple wording.

Secondly, the WooCommerce functionality does not work! Of course, I have followed their step by step on their site, followed the same on another site, I have tried various plugins to do the same or similar and nothing is overriding the Tax labels

Comment: Note: I can quite easily add tax to my items via wooCommerce's plugin Tax settings - that's not the problem.

My problem here is swopping the actual labels to Vat throughout the site.

Comment: PLease see my response

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please add this to the end of your functions.php in your theme folder.

woocommerce_countries_ex_tax_or_vat - http://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Countries.html#372

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_countries_inc_tax_or_vat', function () {
  return __( '(VAT)', 'woocommerce' );
});
```

Or, if you’re changing the “(ex. Tax)” label then this hook http://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Countries.html#362:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_countries_ex_tax_or_vat', function () {
  return __( '(ex. VAT)', 'woocommerce' );
});
```

And the third one you should set up is :

```
function woo_change_tax_label($label) {      
    $label = 'VAT';
    return $label;
    }
add_filter( 'woocommerce_countries_tax_or_vat', 'woo_change_tax_label' );
```

`woocommerce_countries_tax_or_vat` http://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Countries.html#352